# SQL Server: Insert row AND update previous duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like:

```
Attributes
------------------------------------
Id | UserId | Key | Value | Active |
```

I would like to insert a new row into this table, and for every row that has the same UserId and Key, I'd like to set Active to 0.

The merge statement seems like a convenient choice here, but I'm not sure how to perform two actions at once, ie:

```
MERGE INTO Attributes AS Target
USIN (<values>) AS Source (<columns>)
    ON Target.Key = Source.Key AND Target.UserId = Source.Uid
WHEN MATCHED <update, then insert>
WHEN NOT MATCHED <insert>
```

I could definitely do this in two queries, but I was wondering if there's a way to do what I'm proposing in one.

Comment: It's still two separate actions, so what is the gain in using one statement? Also [please read this in full](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). `MERGE` does not buy you anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly do it in a single `MERGE` statement, but it won't be pretty. `MERGE` will perform only one action for every row in `Source`, so it won't do both `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` and you can't both update and insert for `MATCHED`; you would need to select one row for every existing row, plus one row for the row you actually want to insert in order to do what you want using just a `MERGE`.

You are better off just using 2 queries.

Comment: Good call. I'll use two queries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do `MATCHED` and `NOT MATCHED` in the same `MERGE` statement. `WHEN MATCHED THEN <do something> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN <do something else>`

Comment: Yes, I meant that for each **row**, `MERGE` only does one or the other.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just reread your answer and realized that's what you meant.

Comment: Either way I think Ben Jaspers is right; I should be doing this in two queries for readability if nothing else. This won't be a common enough action for extra overhead to matter (and a merge that complex might be inefficient on its own anyway).

Comment: Also please see that [`MERGE` has some other issues that shouldn't be ignored](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).